# Possible to change widget position when run?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Is possible change widget layout when app run?

I want change widget position to left or right side of screen if `bool` change to `true` or `false`.

For example inside `Row` I have widget in centre. But I want change widget on outside to left or right:

```
 return Container(

        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[

// Need change this widget position
            new Container(
                child:
                Text(‘Outside’)
),



            new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                   ‘Middle’
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),



 //               new Container(
 //                   child:
 //                   Text(‘Outside’)
 //   ),



          ],
        ),

      );
```

Is possible change `Container` position? I have try use alignment but I cannot make work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a state variable outside build to hold the status, use `setState()` to update the status (this causes `build()` to re-run. In `build()` chose a different layout strategy depending on the state variable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for reply! I am do this. My issue is if it possible avoid duplicate code here. For example by use `MainAxisAlignment` for move `Container` to other side?

Comment: So you want the `Container()` before or after `Expanded()` depending on a state? You can store the Container in a variable at the beginning of `build()` and then add it depending on the state where you need it. `var container = ...; var expanded = ...; children: state ? <Widget>[container, expanded] : <Widget>[expanded, container ], ...`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for reply! I can do you way but still must repeat code. Is no way can use alignment for do this?

Comment: I don't think so. There is a new Dart feature work in progress to make building lists easier that was initiated exactly for such cases.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! I was think there must be way swap side by use alignment. for example `MainAxisAlignment.end`?

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have `Row`. If specify `Container` before `Expanded` in widget class it go on left side. If put `Container` below `Expanded` in code it go on right side. My question is I can achieve this by use `MainAxisAlignment` instead of you suggestion to use `var container ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Row's parameter `textDirection`. If you set this to `TextDirection.rtl` it should switch the order of its children. I don't believe this propagates downwards but you may want to test that to make sure.